# How to view multipe reports in 1 crystal reports viewer?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, reportviewer, subreport

How can I open 2 seperate reports in 1 crystal reports viewer at a single time?

And when previewing the report, I see that my subreport doesn't filled its parent control width, how to Subreport width fill its parent width?

I use crystal reports for visual studio 2010.

Comment: Why the '-2'? This is a valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't have multiple reports show in the same viewer as the report gets bound to the viewer. Now there are some ways of getting around that and making it look like you have multiple reports showing in one viewer:

1) You could append multiple viewers to your page and suppress all toolbars.

2) You could make each of the reports into a subreport and put them into one report.

3) If the report is not going to be interactive(ie - paging, links, drill down, etc) you could just generate pdf's for each report and merge them.

And about your subreport not showing correctly: you need to format the subreport seperately to make it fit your page. Just formatting the subreport container will not help, you have to format the subreport itself.

Hope that helps!

Chris

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need you show steps to solve this problem. This is my first time using crystal reports

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't do your work for you. I gave you three possible scenarios to choose from. Scenario 1 will happen in Visual Studio, adding multiple viewers to a page. Scenario 2 will happen in Crystal, adding subreports to an existing report (since you already have a subreport I assume you know how to do that). Scenario 3 would  also happen in Visual Studio. So choose an option that you think will fit your needs and then do some more research.

Comment: Crystal doesn't support nested subreports so if you already have subreports in one of the reports you cannot add it as a subreport to another report. Generating PDFs and merging them is the only option.

Comment: @Lan, not necessarily. You couldn't just throw any existing report in as a subreport. You would have to build your main report in a way that you could link your other reports as subreports. You can have multiple subreports in a report. Whether it is a smart thing to and how well it performs is another question. You can as a matter of fact just create multiple groups and just throw random reports in there without any linking. It will take a long time to run (depending on the reports), but it will display each report just fine.

Comment: @campagnolo_1 I need more time for learn Crystal Report. But now I know ways you say with me. Thanks for answer :)

Comment: What do you mean by `you could append viewers to the page and suppress all toolbars.` anyone can give me the steps for this? thanks